# Do I need to consider Etag in Azure Table Storage when performing Update element?

Tags: azure-table-storage, etag

I don't know if I need to consider ETag for preventing multiple threads operating a single entity at the same time.
Below is my current implementation:

```cs
public void UpdateElement(T element)
{
    Exceptions.ThrowIfNull(element, "record");
    var partitionKey = element.PartitionKey;
    var rowKey = element.RowKey;
    var result = Table.Execute(TableOperation.Retrieve<T>(partitionKey, rowKey));
    if (result?.Result != null)
    {
        Table.Execute(TableOperation.Replace(element));
    }
}
```

So what I'm trying to achieve here is, thread A & thread B are operating the same entity at the same time, and thread A updated this entity first. When thread B is trying to update it, we should give thread B an error saying "you can not perform the update action".

Comment: Where does variable `element` come from? If it's from server query, then it already contains the ETag, you don't need to retrieve the entity again like `var result = Table.Execute(TableOperation.Retrieve<T>(partitionKey, rowKey))`. Besides, if `element` is constructed from client side and doesn't come from server query, your code above doesn't really check ETag as your expectation since `element` doesn't contains any ETag.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! But I want to know which value we should give for setting a Etag. for example, I have two threads, thread A & thread B, they both want to update an existing element ELEMENT. in this scenario, how should we set the Etag for A&B's operation? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ETag` is not designed to be set manually. Instead, it's designed for **Read-Edit-Write** scenarios and preventing **Dirty Write** due to concurrent operations.

- If the variable `element` is fetched from server query, it already contains the `ETag` coming from server side, you don't need to retrieve it again like `var result = Table.Execute(TableOperation.Retrieve<T>(partitionKey, rowKey))`
- If the variable `element` is constructed from client side, retrieving `ETag` from server side and set it to `element` doesn't make much sense.
- To *explicitly disable the concurrency check*, you should set the ETag property to a wildcard (`*`) before you execute the replace operation.  i.e.

  ```cs
  customer.ETag = "*";
  ```

#### Further Reading

- [Managing Concurrency in Microsoft Azure Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/managing-concurrency-in-microsoft-azure-storage-2/)
- [Dealing with TableStorage ETag with SDK >= 2.1](https://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2013/10/29/dealing-with-tablestorage-etag-with-sdk-gt-2-1.aspx)